# Python: Groupby and sum respective rows and update dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

**Input** `df`:

```
Store   Category    Item    tot_table
11      AA          Apple   13.5
11      AA          Orange  13.5
11      BB          Potato  11.5
11      BB          Carrot  11.5
12      AA          Apple   10  
12      BB          Potato  9
12      BB          Carrot  9
```

Need to perform `df.groupby('Store')['tot_table'].unique().sum()` , but this line of code doesn't work out.

**Expected output** `df`:

```
Store   Category    Item    split_table     tot_table
11      AA          Apple   13.5                25
11      AA          Orange  13.5                25
11      BB          Potato  11.5                25
11      BB          Carrot  11.5                25
12      AA          Apple   10                  19
12      BB          Potato  9                   19
12      BB          Carrot  9                   19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `unique`/`sum`:

```
df['tot_table'] = (df.groupby('Store')['tot_table']
                     .transform(lambda s: s.unique().sum())
                  )
```

output:

```
   Store Category    Item  tot_table
0     11       AA   Apple       25.0
1     11       AA  Orange       25.0
2     11       BB  Potato       25.0
3     11       BB  Carrot       25.0
4     12       AA   Apple       19.0
5     12       BB  Potato       19.0
6     12       BB  Carrot       19.0
```